# PayPal Payment Button for Variable Amount

Tags: php, paypal

I want to insert different payment buttons in my car sharing web app. The button amounts are based on DB data inserted by sellers.

Sellers offer service(for $) -> Buyer searches for service -> list of services with related payment buttons are displayed

HOW IT WORKS
The seller writes his amount $, the amount goes to DB. 
Whenever the buyer searches, a list is displayed with different sellers and related payment buttons (with related amounts).

I tried to modify PayPal button string, inserting the price variable, but PayPal does not allow these modifications anymore.

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) != 0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
            $user = $row['user'];
            $price= $row['price'];  

            echo '$user' . $userTrip->getName();                                   

            echo 'href="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?business=email@email.com&cmd=_xclick&currency_code=EUR&amount=' . $price. '&item_name=Pagamento%20Trip">Pay withPaypal</a>';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PayPal *does* allow those modifications. The problem with your example is you also have to pass a valid receiver email address in the "business" parameter. (`business=email@email.com` is not valid)

---

A better experience would be to integrate [Smart Payment Buttons](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client), instead of a simple link.

Normally you need the ClientID of each receiver (this is preferred, since PayPal account emails can change) -- but alternatively, you can use [your own](https://www.paypal.com/signin?returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Fapplications) ClientID and specify the receiver's PayPal email address in the `payee` field:

```
                    purchase_units: [{
                        payee: {
                            email_address: 'replacewithrealemail@somewhere.com'
                        },
                        amount: {
                            value: <?= $price =>
                        }
                    }]
```

Perhaps that should be `'<$= $userTrip->getEmail() =>'` , or however you're meant to obtain and echo it to this Javascript array you're outputting.

Comment: Hi preston, I did changed the email because I did not want to post any real email here. I tried with a valid email, I am redirected to paypal. The problem is that the money do not arrive to the seller, they are refunded to the buyer

Comment: Does the seller have a PayPal business account in good standing? Do they have a EUR balance open? If the payment was pending, did they accept it within the 30 day window?  If so, ask PayPal's support why it was refunded. In any case, not an issue for Stack Overflow.